# How to increase the number of indexed images from submitted image sitemap?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I had added images in my sitemap a week ago, but the number of images indexed in the Google Webmaster Tools has not displayed any tendency to increase. The number of images submitted is about 200,000 but the number of images indexed keeps floating around 10,000.

I hosted my images on AWS S3, and I used different URL `.s3.amazonaws.com` instead of my domain, but I provide a `robots.txt` file in the root directory of the bucket (per [this instruction](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636)). In the sitemap XML the images are grouped in each content page `<loc>`, but the images filenames doesn't give any relevant information about the content of the page. They are just a bunch of random numbers.

Is there any way I can do to increase the number of indexed images in the Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the troubleshooting link at the bottom of your link? [Troubleshooting Sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178644)  How many days has it been since you submitted it?

Comment: The indexed images already hit 10,000 from the second day after the image tags into the sitemaps. But after 7 days, it stays around that number. In fact it kind of decreasing. The HTML pages are indexed around the number of pages submitted. It's the images I'm worrying about. I'm wondering if there are special tips or tricks for that.

Comment: It's been ONE WEEK. Do you even realize how big the internet is? ;)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just don't like waiting for a month just to wait for another month. I think it's better to collect public experiences as soon as possible. That way I know if there is something wrong I do based on your opinions before it's too late.
I'm absolutely going to update this question next month :)

Answer (score 2):

If the number of links are decreasing over time, Google could be viewing some URL's as duplicate content - Google has image recognition capabilities which allows it to compare images, and will not index duplicates that it finds.

See the following for more on that:  [Beware: Google Getting Even Better at Identifying Duplicate Images](https://www.searchenginenews.com/blog/entry/beware-google-updates-image-search) And refer to the [Image publishing guidelines from Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114016)
, if you haven't already.

Be sure to check if there are any crawl errors being displayed in Google Webmaster tools. Also note that there is a limit to the number of URL's in a single sitemap: 50K per sitemap file. See "How big can my Sitemap be?" here:  [Sitemaps.org:  FAQ's](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you only to wait (about 1 month). It depends on you site's information updating frequency.

I had had the similar situation, but after a months all the images appeared in Google Image Search Results.

Comment: Thanks, it's really good to know that there is another person experiencing the same. I'll put a notice next month.